# Is "Per amorem ad astra" a nice thought to put on the birth card of my firstborn?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I have no knowledge of Latin whatsoever but always loved the "ad astra" as an aspiration. Since the theme of our birth card is astronauts, I was wondering if the following sentence is correct and conveys what I mean:

per amorem ad astra - through love to the stars

Meaning that we will love her to the fullest and help her become the best version of herself :)

Thanks in advance
Emiel

Comment: I don't know, but congratulations!

Comment: I'd say the Latin is correct, and the sentiment is delightful!

Answer (score 7):

Being a Latin teacher!  I would probably use the ablative of means - amore ad astra. But I suppose love itself in a journey that you go "through" so Per amorem.

Comment: Welcome to the site!